# Format implements/extends/throws on new line

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I want my java formatted with throws, implements, and extends on a new line. Is this possible in Eclipse?

```java
public DataRecord fromFile(File file, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
```

to

```java
public DataRecord fromFile(File file, InputStream inputStream)
  throws IOException {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse navigate to:

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`

Then, to change your formatting preferences, click `Edit`.

There navigate to `Line Wrapping -> Wrapping Settings`.

For methods:

Open the option for `Method Declarations`, where you can select the formatting behavior for `throws`.

For class declarations:

Open the option for `Class Declarations`, where you can select the formatting behavior for `extends` and `implements`.

Comment: any idea what's happening https://github.com/revelc/formatter-maven-plugin/discussions/732

Comment: none of this matters if the line length fails to exceed the configured value for org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit

Comment: @caduceus Did you select "Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width"?